# Convergence of sequences elevated to a power

Tags: real-analysis

I have been having trouble proving these two statements:

Prove that if $0<r<1$ and $x_n \rightarrow r$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $(x_n)^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

I thought of saying if $x_n$ converges to $r$, then $\forall\epsilon>0$  We need to find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$|r^n-0|=r^n<\epsilon \\ \forall n\geq N$$
$$n\log{r}<\log\epsilon$$
$$n>\frac{\log\epsilon}{\log{r}}$$
Since $\log{r}<0$. Then choose $N >\frac{\log\epsilon}{\log{r}}$. But is this a correct method of proof, taking the value of $r$?

For the second proof:

Prove that this is false: If $x_n \rightarrow 1$ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$, then $(x_n)^n\rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

I know the counter example of $e=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ but I don't know how to prove it without this counter example.
I tried:

Assume $(x_n)^n\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then:
$$n\log{x_n}=\log1=0$$
$$\log{x_n}=0$$
$$x_n=1$$
Which is obviously wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon=\min(r, \frac{1-r}{2})$. There is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $|x_n-r|\lt \epsilon$.

Thus if $n\gt N$ then $0\lt x_n\lt r+\frac{1-r}{2}=\frac{1+r}{2}\lt 1$, and therefore
$$0\lt x_n^n \lt \left(\frac{1+r}{2}\right)^n.$$
But $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+r}{2}\right)^n=0$, so by 
Squeezing $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^n=0$.

For your second problem, the counterexample is enough. You cannot do "better," since there certainly are sequences $(x_n)$ with limit $1$ such that the sequence $(x_n^n)$ has limit $1$.

Comment: But the counter example assumes I know how to prove that, but I don't?

Comment: Note that by the Bernoulli Inequality (or the Binomial Theorem) we have $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\ge 1+n\cdot \frac{1}{n}=2$, so if $x_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$ then the sequence $(x_n^n)$ does not have limit $1$. (In fact the sequence does have a limit, and it is $e$, but you don't need to prove that.)

Comment: By the way, what was your intuition for the first one?

Comment: Are you asking why I wrote it up in that style. with the "magic" $\frac{1-r}{2}$? The idea is that if the limit is $r\lt 1$, then after a while the terms $x_n$ are below some fixed $s\lt 1$, and therefore the $n$-th power is less than $s^n$, which goes nicely to $0$. So I took half the distance from $r$ to $1$, which is $\frac{1-r}{2}$, and concluded that after a while $x_n$ is below $r+\frac{1-r}{2}$. It really is visualizing the geometry of the line.